# I want to built a custom 404 page for my website

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, http-status-code-404, css-position, errordocument

[This is 404 page background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIl7B.jpg) I want to make a custom 404 page with this image as background and use the bootstrap button to be clicked on.

into this image, there is a black rectangle on it I want to keep the home link button I tried everything to keep this button on same place for evry device but it shifts different position in defferent devices

is it possible to fix button with background image position with if yes then how to do it..

Comment: One thought is to use an IFrame with set width and height to load the page the same on all device's...

Comment: You have not added any code to your question. We need to see what you have tried so far. Please add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your question also contains several grammatical errors. Please see [this guide on how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well.

Comment: Can I suggest a title change: "Formatting a responsive custom 404 page for my website"

Answer (score 0):

According to the [HTTPD documentation for ErrorDoument](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument), the path to a file must be relative to the configured DocumentRoot, ie. if /opt/lampp/htdocs/abc/404.html is the file you want to use, and the DocumentRoot is set to /opt/lampp/htdocs, then you must use ErrorDocument 404 /abc/404.html.

If you want to set the ErrorDocuent in a .htaccess file, you must ensure that AllowOverride FileInfo is set for the directory the .htaccess file is stored in.